# Login through Linkedin in Android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am working on login through linkedin in my android app, I have written the code but the problem is that it requires linkedin app installed on my device and if its not present it will ask to download, but I want that if app is not installed in the device, login should be done through browser (like facebook does). How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Please Show your code

Comment: You could use linkedIn sdk

Comment: @AkhilSoman I am using linkedin sdk only..but it ask for compulsory app installation on device which I don't want.

Comment: In that case if you could use FB instead of linkedIn, in fb sdk, this is possible even without an fb app in the phone.

Comment: @AkhilSoman Linkedin is my requirement presently..Thanks

Comment: Please check "custom tabs" in android i am not entirely sure it would work... But still worth a look

Comment: @AkhilSoman Sure..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The native LinkedIn application is presently required in order for the LinkedIn Mobile SDK to successfully authenticate.

Web-based authentication is on the roadmap, but in the meantime, you require the app to be installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..there is no other way to do this??

Comment: @user3484325 None I know of, sorry

Comment: @TonyVincent is web-based authentication functioning now?

Answer (score 0):

Now we can use LinkedIn V2 APIs to login via Android...

If you're willing to use 3rd party libs, I've created a lightweight "unofficial" SDK for Android, you can use it from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/AbdAllahAbdElFattah13/LinkedIn-SDK-Android.

It's unofficial since LinkedIn has deprecated and stopped supporting their old mobile SDKs as per [this link](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates).

We also use it in our production apps, so it should be working fine. :)